# ASP.Net Generate and Save CSV using System.Web.HttpResponse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, save

Hi I'm using the following code to generate a CSV file containing data from a dataset. The CSV generates fine and a prompt box displays so that the user can either open or save the csv file. What I'm wondering is whether it's possible to save the CSV file?

Thanks for any help

Edited with solution (NB I don't need the prompt box to open as I'll be writing additional code to generate and save a number of files and then display links to them). This saves the dataset as a CSV on our server.

```
Protected Sub exportBtn_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim ds1 As DataSet
    ds1 = csvdownload.ReturnNewPledges()
    Dim csv As New chartnew.csvhelper
    Dim strData1 As String = csv.Export(ds1, True)

    Dim todaydate As Date = Date.Now.Date
    Dim todaystr As String = todaydate.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
    Dim filename As String = todaystr & "_filename.csv"

    Dim saveDir As String = "writedir\files\"
    Dim appPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
    Dim filePath As String = appPath + saveDir + filename

    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(filePath)
    writer.Write(strData1)
    writer.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't really follow you: You say that the user can either open or save the CSV and you are asking if it is possible to do that?!? Do you mean to save the CSV also on server side?

Comment: The slashes in the filename will be lost when saving the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StreamWriter:

```
    Dim SwFromFile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName)
    SwFromFile.Write(strData1)
    SwFromFile.Flush()
    SwFromFile.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to us, works a treat. I re-worked it slightly for what I needed if anyone's interested...Dim saveDir As String = "writedir\files\"
        Dim appPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
        Dim filePath As String = appPath + saveDir + "test2.txt"
        
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(filePath)
        writer.Write(strData1)
        writer.Close()